get data from array into array in mysql JSON column
MYSQL JSON column has array values ​​built into the array,
I want to retrieve indexes containing certain values ​​from this array with mysql commands.
JSON column;
id=1 // There is only one row in the table
[
 [57,0,0,0,0,53,"Eylül - 2024",0,0,[0,0,1500,""]],
 [56,7,0,17267904,0,53,"Eylül - 2024","0","1",[9,1262,238,"1~0003"]],
 [55,7,0,17267904,0,53,"Eylül - 2024","0","1",[9,1426,74,1]],
 [54,6,0,17267904,0,53,"Eylül - 2024","0","8",[9,1426,74,1]],
 [53,4,0,17267904,0,53,"Eylül - 2024","0","6",[9,1426,74,1]],
 [52,7,0,17267904,0,53,"Eylül - 2024","0","1",[9,1426,74,1]],
 [51,7,0,17267904,0,53,"Eylül - 2024","0","5",[9,1426,74,1]]
 .....
]

The 9th elements of the arrays in the row are the row numbers of the people in the recording story. For example, I want to take all the elements of the arrays whose 9th element is 1 and create a new array and use it.
 [52,7,0,17267904,0,53,"Eylül - 2024","0","/*
                                     The person I'm looking for =*/ 1",[9,1426,74,1]],

sample result ; 
[
 [56,7,0,17267904,0,53,"Eylül - 2024","0","1",[9,1262,238,"1~0003"]],
 [55,7,0,17267904,0,53,"Eylül - 2024","0","1",[9,1426,74,1]],
 [52,7,0,17267904,0,53,"Eylül - 2024","0","1",[9,1426,74,1]]
]


However, although I tried a variety of similar things, I could not get the result I wanted.
In summary; If the 9th element in the subarrays is the searched value, I want to get the entire array.
I want to select and retrieve arrays within array in MYSQL JSON column

select json_arrayagg(j.a) as _result
from vt_tb_cari_haraket_2024 
cross join json_table(vt_st_cari_haraket_json, '$[*]' columns(a json path '$')) as j
where j.a->>'$[8]' = '1'
group by id;

Result:
[
  [56, 7, 0, 17267904, 0, 53, "Eylül - 2024", "0", "1", [9, 1262, 238, "1~0003"]],
  [55, 7, 0, 17267904, 0, 53, "Eylül - 2024", "0", "1", [9, 1426, 74, 1]],
  [52, 7, 0, 17267904, 0, 53, "Eylül - 2024", "0", "1", [9, 1426, 74, 1]]
]

Demo:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fhMr8VtNjNY5B6QPyhS9JN/0
Note that the JSON_TABLE() function requires MySQL 8.0 or later.

Thank you very much, this is very important for me, I will try it and let you know the result, good work.

Hello, I implemented your solution but it gives an error message like this: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(vt_st_cari_haraket_json, '$[*]' columns(a json path '$)) as j ' at line 3, Our data fetch type is defined as fetch_object in the PDO class. the line is like this: $this->pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, \PDO::FETCH_OBJ); –

and unfortunately the mysql version of the server I use is:
Server version: 5.7.40-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server - (GPL)
In this case, can a different path be designed?

Yes, it involves two steps: first upgrade to a currently supported version of MySQL, then use the solution I provided above. Is it unreasonable? MySQL 8.0 has been available since 2018. MySQL 5.7 has been unsupported for almost a year.

In this project, we are using an anonymous server for rent, so we cannot intervene in the version, we plan to set up our own server when the project is completed, but now it seems like it would be better to bring this plan forward, it will still need some time,

When the program runs in the future, there will be tens of thousands of rows in that json cell, so extracting the entire data and parsing it with PHP will require unnecessary CPU and RAM usage. To prevent this, it will be very important that we use the query you suggested. Thank you wholeheartedly for your help.

You might also consider not using JSON at all, but storing the data in normal rows and columns. Then you can use MySQL 5.7-compatible SQL syntax to request just the rows you want, using conditions in the WHERE clause. Storying data in JSON often makes queries more complex and inefficient.

A 75% time saving and 90% CPU usage minimization was calculated for the use of JSON cell type at scales just below large data sizes, so it was decided to proceed in this way, but the technique is very new and seems to be a subject that has never been covered before us.

The same as all forms of denormalization, it can improve one type of query, but at the expense of other queries.
